# Running Google Cloud SQL Proxy on background for python

Tags: python, subprocess, google-cloud-sql

I'm running Google Cloud SQL Proxy on a Raspberry with Ubuntu mate, but currently, I have to open one terminal to start the proxy and another to run my python SQL script. I need to automate this process.

To start the proxy I run:

```
cd my_proxy_dir
sudo ./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=./ -instance_name -credential_file=./key_file.json
```

The last line of the output is

> Ready for connections
>
> █ (the square is blinking, the terminal is blocked, the proxy owns the terminal)

In a second terminal I run my python script which includes a MySQL connection to the cloud instance, and the output of the first terminal reports the new connection, at the end of my python script the connection is also notified:

> (timestamp) Ready for connections ...
>
> (timestamp) New connection ...
>
> (timestamp) Connection finished for ...
>
> █ (the square is blinking, the terminal is blocked, the proxy owns the terminal)

Now, since I'm working with python, I created a thread because I was unable to run the proxy starting command without blocking. This is my run method:

```
my_thread...    
    def run(self)
            subprocess.call(['sudo', './proxy/cloud_sql_proxy', '-dir=./proxy/', '-instances=instance_name','-credential_file=./proxy/key_file.json', '&'])
           print('pass')
```

It never print "pass" until I terminate the thread with thread.terminate()

Then what I do

```
my_proxy_thread = Thread_proxy()
my_proxy_thread.start()
time.sleep(10) #because I don't know when the proxy socket has bee created so I only wait
# Once created the socket
do_my_mysql_stuff()
my_proxy_thread.terminate() # kill the thread and also the proxy socket in the bad way
```

And it works, my proxy socket is created, my_sql works ok but I have no control of the proxy output, I don't know what is happening, if it failed or is closed, working... I cannot send the instruction to close the socket. And I get a mess in my terminal where I do logging because of the subprocess command output

What do I need?

1. It would be great if I could get the stdout of the sub-process, so I could realize when the socket has been created and connected, but until now I haven't been able, even with PIPE it blocks.
2. I don't want that the result of the subprocess be printed in the terminal, because I'm using the logging package, so the stdout of the subprocess creates disorder in my terminal logs :(
3. Send a Control + C to the subprocess to stop the proxy instead of terminating the read so roughly

Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0):

1. you're going to have dig deeper into linux process management to get what you want done. Firstly `subprocess.call` will pass the arguments directly to process without the intermediate shell. The `&` is part of the shell, so you need to set `Shell=true` for it to be interpreted correctly.
2. For the result of the   subprocess, if you're using a terminal emulator on the pi itself, you can instead of running the proxy directly, have it open a new terminal which runs the proxy. You could also just have it append to a file and then have another window tailing the file.
3. You can just keep the proxy running in the background and don't need to start it up each time. You should be able to connect directly via ip directly and don't have to run the proxy at all.